# How can I prevent line breaks between words without exceeding the page margins?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, hyphenation, layout

I'm currently writing a legal paper in LaTeX that requires me to cite a lot of law in my text, for example something like

> Das in § 37 Abs. 2 BetrVG normierte Lohnausfallprinzip wirkt anspruchserhaltend.

Our style guide specifies that citations of laws are not allowed to be broken up into multiple lines, so in my example

> § 37 Abs. 2 BetrVG

has to stay together in one line.

I know that I can force Latex to make no line breaks in multiple ways. I can use an `\mbox`, I can use a nonbreaking space via `\,` and I can also use a skip via `~`. Unfortunately, all of those solutions lead to the quotation exceeding the page margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0in,
            left=7cm,
            right=2.5cm,
            top=2.5cm,
            bottom=2.5cm,
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
Das in § 37\,Abs.\,2\,BetrVG normierte Lohnausfallprinzip wirkt anspruchserhaltend; der Lohnanspruch aus dem Arbeitsvertrag, der eigentlich nach dem Grundsatz \glqq Kein Lohn ohne Arbeit!\grqq\ entfiele, bleibt erhalten. Anspruchsgrundlage ist somit nicht §\,37\,Abs.\,2\,BetrVG selbst, sondern der Arbeitsvertrag
\end{document}
```

compiles to this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering whether there's any way to prevent Latex from breaking lines without exceeding page margins, by recarranging and hyphenating the other words in that paragraph.

Comment: `\,` isn't breakable: use say `\thin` defined as `\newcommand\thin{\hspace{.17em}}`

Comment: although in the first line you have a normal space after`§` and later a thin space, you could use normal spaces everywhere

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry, I don't get that. How would that fix my problem (btw, the missing nonbreaking space after the § is just a typo, not done on purpose). If I replace every nonbreaking space with that \thin command, I get the exact same result with exceeded page margins.

Comment: If you have long unbreakable strings like `§\,37\,Abs.\,2\,BetrVG` then even microtype will not always be able to find a good break, and you will have to fall back to sloppy to add ugly space elsewhere to compensate. If you have multiple short strings with stretch so `§ 37 Abs. 2 BetrVG` or `§\thin 37\thin Abs.\thin 2\thin BetrVG`  with `\newcommand\thin{\hspace{.17em plus .05em minus .05em}}` then line breaking is easy

Comment: Off-topic: Unless you're deliberately looking to implement pre-1997 hyphenation rules, don't load `babel` with the option `german`. Instead. use the option `ngerman`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But this does not prevent line breaking within that string altogether, it just makes it less likely, correct?

Comment: if you do not want §\,37\,Abs.\,2\,BetrVG to break over a line then your answer is fine. my suggestion was to allow it to break as small words are easier. (I'm trying to resist suggesting using english to avoid scary long strings like `anspruchserhaltend` :-)

Comment: I would totally agree with you if it was completely up to me, but unfortunately, I have to stick to the style guide my university handed out. And yeah, German is a really awful language for typesetting considering the prevalence of extremely long words, hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've just found the answer to my own question (sorry for the bother). You can either use the `\sloppy` command or (and I'd recommend this, because it doesn't degrade the paragraph quality as much) the `microtype` package in addition to the nonbreaking spaces to get exactly what I wanted.